# EPPlus ExcelPackage.GetSpreadsheetByteArray "Cannot access a closed stream"

Tags: epplus

If I run the following code with the second line commented out as shown, no exceptions are thrown.  If I comment out the first line and uncomment the second line, ExcelPackage.GetAsByteArray() throws exception "Cannot access a closed Stream".  What am I doing wrong?

```
public byte[] GetSpreadsheetByteArray()
{
    using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(@"Config\StarterSpreadsheet.xlsm")),true))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");
        //ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Copy("Sheet1","MySheet");

        return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your confirmed `Sheet1` exists?

Comment: Yes, Sheet1 does exist in Config\StarterSpreadsheet.xlsm.